# Not able to execute a Webdriver Java Code from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, ant, webdriver

I recently configured Web-driver in eclipse and also configured ant and I was able to execute a project. 
Recently I created 1 more project and wrote first Java code and when I click on run button , it is not able to execute it even though it has no errors. 
Here is the error it is throwing when I try to execute.

```
Class not found Dashboard
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Dashboard
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at     org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:693)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:429)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Have you made sure that you have the Selenium and Junit jars in your build path?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have selenium-java-2.x.jar and JUnit/TestNG jar in you classpath. Also make sure your tests are in classpath.
To set a classpath right Click on **Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> "Add JARs" or "Add External JARs"**.